# Windows mobile microphone low level properties

Tags: windows-mobile, audio, microphone

I would like to know if there is any managed or unmanaged library for accesing microphone properties in windows mobile. I want to collect real-time info from the microphone: decibels, tone and so on...

Any idea? Any .dll for that in windows mobile?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in facility in Windows Mobile for doing audio analysis.  However, there is a standard API for capturing raw digital audio from the microphone.  Here are the functions you can use to work with audio capture:

waveInOpen, waveInPrepareHeader, waveInUnprepareHeader, waveInAddBuffer, waveInStart,
waveInStop, waveInClose